# VBScript MoveFile - Microsoft VBScript runtime error: File not found (but file is renamed)

Tags: vbscript

I have a strange error which I don't think I should be getting.

I pick up a file and rename it, and then I get an error to say the file is not found, but when I look in the directory the file is actually renamed correctly.
How can I get rid of the error?

Here's my code:

```
Dim Fso
Set Fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Wscript.Echo("MoveFile('"+WdFile+"', '"+TargetFile+"')")
If (Fso.MoveFile(WdFile, TargetFile)) Then 'This is line 140 where the error occurs
    Call writeToHistory("info", "File successfully renamed from " & WdFile & " to " & TargetFileName)
Else
    Call writeToHistory("warn", "File could not be renamed for event " & WdReason & " file=" & WdFile)
End If
```

And the output in the console:

```
MoveFile('D:\Temp\RenameFiles\RS_FMT25589.pdf', 
'D:\Temp\RenameFiles\output\hca4l.mp.Q2.FMT25589.wt165179.pdf')
C:\Scripts\RS_renameJobFiles.vbs(140, 1) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: File not found
```

Comment: I think that we need to see a bit more of the code surrounding the `If` block. I suspect it being part of a loop and that the order of actions taken might srew it up.

Comment: You can verify that `WdFile` is found by the FSO using `fso.FileExists(WdFile)`